# Module grunt-contrib-coffee for Grunt creates subfolder for each file

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm, grunt-contrib-concat

My question is in subject. I have the following config for this module:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    coffee: {
        options: {
            bare: true
        },
        scripts: {
            expand: true,
            flatten: true,
            cwd: 'coffee/',
            src: ['*.coffee'],
            dest: 'js/',
            ext: '.js'
        }
    }
});
```

After compilation Grunt creates subfolder for each output js-file with the same directory name, instead put all output files in single directory "js/". Sorry for my bad English and thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, It was my error. Config is right. Question closed.